# Why is my form using GET instead of POST?

Tags: php, forms

When I try to submit a form from `mysite/form` to `mysite/import` using this form:

```
<form action="../import" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="hidden" value="hi">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The import site doesn't seem to recieve the post. I get redirected to the import site, but the data doesn't seem to be there. When checking I discovered this:

`var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` gives `string(3) "GET"`

`var_dump($_POST)` gives `array(0) {}`

`var_dump($_REQUEST)` gives `array(0) {}`

When using the same form from the import site, everything works, and when I use the form page to some random other page, it also works.
I've already tried to add `method='POST'` to everything, or adding `formmethod="post" formaction="../import"` to the submit button, but nothing works.

Comment: @cybermonkey where? You mean or `<input />`, or what?

Comment: @cybermonkey — No. The end tag for input elements is forbidden in HTML.

Comment: then why is it ../import instead of just import

Comment: Look at the Network tab of the developer tools in your browser. Look at the HTTP requests being made. Do you see the request? Is it POST? What response does it get? Is there a redirect which triggers a subsequent GET request?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 because you go from `mysite/form` to `mysite/import`, which is `../import` as seen from `mysite/form`?

Comment: @Quentin That worked, thanks! There was something wrong with using `mysite/import`, so instead used `mysite/import/` in `action` and it worked. (full story: somehow there was something called a `status code 301 moved permanently` at `mysite/import`, and then changed itself to `mysite/import/` and then said `status code 200 OK`, so yea, I have no idea what how or who)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

found the problem.

Apperently there is something wrong with using `mysite/import`, and when I changed the action to `action='../import/'` (instead of `action='../import'`) it worked.

Comment: Probably means you're relying on the directory index (for the web server to automatically pick the index.php file in the import directory). You should provide the filename in your form action (e.g. ../import/index.php)

Comment: @jhilgeman you're right, but thing is, Im a little nitpicky, and it bothers me a lot when the webadress ends with `index.php`, and this worked fine.

Comment: Okay. Just be aware that it can be a security risk (or even a configuration problem). If a hacker ever gets control of the ability to change the DocumentRoot setting, they could make your form post to a different file of their choosing. Or if someone changes the order of the values in that config or inserts a higher-priority file into the directory, it could break your form, even if it's not intended to be malicious.

Comment: @jhilgeman Thanks for the warning. The site's not public, so I don't think it'll be much of a problem.
And there really isn't a solution for it? How do other sites do something like this?

Comment: Some sites try to mitigate the security risk by using .htaccess files in conjunction with mod_rewrite to handle cosmetic URLs directly. The catch is that .htaccess is only for Apache and also is a slight performance hit on every request.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have an intermediate redirect. There's nothing wrong with your code at first glance. Turn on developer tools in your browser (make sure the log is preserved so that it doesn't clear when the browser navigates to a new page), and watch the network activity. (You can also use a tool like Fiddler to do this). I'll bet you see a POST followed by a GET redirect to the final page.

The fact that the exact same code works on another site might indicate an .htaccess file or something in play.

Comment: Run Fiddler and make note of what happens when you submit the form.

Comment: Also, look for an .htaccess file anywhere in your folder tree (document root and anything inside). It's a hidden file by default but if it's there, rename it temporarily to something else and try your test again and see if anything changes.

Comment: Found the problem, it was indeed found in the network page thingy. Thanks for the help @jhilgeman